Generate option for dynamically generated dropdown in angular
I'm creating form dynamic form control using this code
this.fieldsData.forEach((ele, i) => {
      if(ele?.inputType=='dropdown')
         {
         const splitValues =ele?.inputValues.split(',');
         ele.DisplayName= ele?.labelName.replace(/###/g,' '); 
         form[ele?.labelName]=new FormControl('',ele?.mandatory=='yes' ? Validators.required : []);
          }
});

in html component i have this code
<form [formGroup]="FormGroup" *ngIf="fieldsData?.length>0">
 <ng-container *ngIf="data.inputType=='dropdown'">
  <select name="select-state" class="form-control"formControlName="{{data.labelName}}">
              <option value="">Select</option> 
  </select>
 </ng-container>
</form>

i want to pass value also which is there in splitValues variable.

sample data

[
    {
        "labelName": "Name",
        "inputType": "textbox",
        "inputValues": "",
        "mandatory": "yes"
    },
    {
        "labelName": "Email",
        "inputType": "textbox",
        "inputValues": "",
        "mandatory": "yes"
    },
    {
        "labelName": "address 2",
        "inputType": "textarea",
        "inputValues": null,
        "mandatory": "yes"
    },
    {
        "labelName": "City",
        "inputType": "dropdown",
        "inputValues": 'value 1,value 2',
        "mandatory": "no"
    }
]

Any solution Thanks

If possible can you share the sample json processed here to create the form with dropdown config in it along with option data?

@user25357539 i have added can you pls check

Create options from data.inputValues in the component instead: split and then loop and create options (as it can have null and '' value, you might add *ngIf="data.inputValues", or maybe set some custom value in that case, depending on your business logic):
<select name="select-state" class="form-control"formControlName="{{data.labelName}}" *ngIf="data.inputValues">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option> 
    <option *ngFor="let val of data.inputValues.split(',')" [value]="val">{{val}}</option>
</select>

